# FileHandler double logs string in a file

Tags: python, python-logging

```
import logging


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(filename='logloglog.log'))
logger.critical('A!')

for handler in logger.handlers:
    handler.close()

logger.addHandler(logging.FileHandler(filename='logloglog.log'))
logger.critical('B!')
```

I am trying to understand why the above code logs `B!` string in `logloglog.log` file twice. It confuses me, since I log both `A!` and `B!` only one time. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

`logger.addHandler` was called twice, so there are two file handlers (pointing at the same filename):

```
>>> logger.handlers
[<FileHandler /home/wglenn/git/modules/logloglog.log (NOTSET)>,
 <FileHandler /home/wglenn/git/modules/logloglog.log (NOTSET)>]
```

By the time `logger.critical('B!')` is called, each handler will write out the event once.

It does not matter that you've closed handlers earlier, [logging will just re-open the resource when it needs to emit, if necessary](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a335d98f19b7fa66159d12932cc9a05eb2d8395f/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1218-L1220).

Comment: I thought I have closed the first one, have not I?

Comment: That just releases the open file resource, it doesn't remove the handler.

Comment: Thank you for your help, wim. I would also add that FileHandler overrides ```.close``` method.

Answer (score 1):

When a new log message arrives the file handler will automatically reopen the file.
so

```
for handler in logger.handlers:
    handler.close()
    logger.removeHandler(handler) // add this line.
```

see the [ref](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).